# Concerning $\mathbb{C}[a,b,c,d]$, with special generators $a,b,c,d$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, jacobian

Let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.
Assume that:

**(1)** Each two of $\{a,b,c,d\}$ are *algebraically independent*.
In other words, the Jacobian of each two of $\{a,b,c,d\}$ is non-zero.

**(2)** $a,b$ are symmetric with respect to the involution $\beta: (x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$
and $c,d$ are skew-symmetric w.r.t. $\beta$.

> Is it true that $\mathbb{C}[a,b,c,d]=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$?
> Or at least (if this helps) that $\mathbb{C}[a,b,c,d,y]=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$?

I wonder if this can be proved or there exists a counterexample?

Of course, for general four elements not satisfying conditions (1) and (2), there exist counterexamples, such as: $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3,y^2,y^3]$.

A counterexample, satisfying condition (2) but not condition (1):
$\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3,y^3,y^5] \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and
$\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3,y^3,y^5,y] \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

A counterexample, satisfying condition (1) but not condition (2):
$\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^2+y, y^2,x^2+y^2]$.

**Edit:** After writing this question I have noticed that $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^2+y^2,y^3,xy]$ is a counterexample. So now I ask:

> What additional conditions guarantee that $\mathbb{C}[a,b,c,d]=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$? Perhaps $\operatorname{Jac}(a+c,b+d) \in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$
> or $\operatorname{Jac}(a+d,b+c) \in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$?

**Remark:** I thought considering $\mathbb{C}(x)[y]$ and $\mathbb{C}(y)[x]$,
but not sure if and how this may help.
For $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^2+y^2,y^3,xy]$, we have:
$\mathbb{C}(x)[x^2,x^2+y^2,y^3,xy]=\mathbb{C}(x)[y]$ and
$\mathbb{C}(y)[x^2,x^2+y^2,y^3,xy]=\mathbb{C}(y)[x]$.

Now also asked in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368232/concerning-mathbbca-b-c-d-with-special-generators-a-b-c-d).

Thank you very much!

---

What if we also assume **(3)**, which says that $\mathbb{C}(a,b,c)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ the field generated by $a,b,c$ (without $d$) equals the field of fractions of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$? Could one find a counterexample? Observe that $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^2+y^2,y^3,xy]$ does not satisfy the new condition **(3)** (not with $a,b,c$ and not with $a,b,d$). Indeed:
$\mathbb{C}(x^2,x^2+y^2,y^3)=\mathbb{C}(x^2,y) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$

Comment: $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^2+y^2,y^3,xy]$ is a counterexample to my above question, so I will edit it.

Comment: Your statement (1) seems contradictory. If any two are algebraically independent, they Jacobian would be non-zero.

Comment: @Mohan, thank you, I meant non-zero. I will fix it now.